# Am I supposed to eat frozen cherries directly

Tags: frozen, cherries

I just got a bag of frozen cherries.

Are they supposed to eat directly, or after they are unfrozen, or after I cook them?

I have never eaten frozen berries before, but just fresh berries.

[image]

Comment: The bag actually says "cherries" on it (it's clearly visible in the full-size photo), so I've removed the "cranberries" from your question - cranberries are a completely different fruit, way more sour than cherries, so they're not generally eaten in the same way.

Comment: Are you asking if it's safe to eat them frozen? Generally asking what to do with an ingredient is off topic here.

Comment: If tart type, you can eat them thawed with a little sugar on top, or make a regular cherry pie with them after thawing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Frozen berries as noted elsewhere have a mushier texture than fresh, so perhaps aren't great for eating in the hand; but they are excellent to pair with plain yogurt.  My wife eats plain yogurt with cherries or blueberries directly out of the freezer, not fully thawed, all the time.  She usually microwaves them briefly to take the chill off and partially thaw them, but I don't believe she fully thaws them.

Smoothies are the other main use I have for frozen berries, they go directly in and make the smoothie nice and cold.

Fully frozen cherries would be too hard to eat really, you could suck on them I guess but that seems like a stretch.

Comment: I eat fully frozen cherries all the time.  There's so much pectin and sugar in them that they are not rock-hard at all.

Comment: @JohnFeltz Hmm, I wonder if this depends on the quality of the cherries then, and/or the temperature of the freezer.  We keep ours in a chest freezer and it seems like they're too hard to eat.

Comment: The ones I eat frozen are dark cherries, mahogany-red to purple-black in color (not sure of variety, purchased in US at variety of grocery stores), and they come out of the freezer section in an upright refrigerator/freezer.

Comment: @JohnFeltz Ah, those might be sweeter.  We get fairly inexpensive Costco cherries, so maybe they're less sweet.

Comment: Nice tart Door county cherries. You let them thaw a day or two in the fridge, scoop out a bowl, sprinkle with sugar, and eat. Or thaw them and bake a pie out of them.

Comment: Chest freezers can typically get (and often set) colder than the freezers in a fridge/freezer combo, or even an upright freezer.

Answer (score 7):

Like all foods, therw is no one correct way to eat cherries.  Here are some things I like to do with frozen berries.  If these cherries are pitted, all of these suggestions apply. Otherwise, you will need to either eat them whole or thaw them and pit them yourself to use them in anything, unless you plan to eat them whole, which is tasty aso well.

Eat them frozen.

Eat them thawed.

Eat them partially thawed.

Eat them frozen in a bowl with cream-- it's like ice cream, but with less work and no sugar.

Blend them with milk and banana for a smoothie.

Put them in a bowl of oatmeal.  You don't even need to thaw them first.

Heat them up with a bit of water, and some sweetener if you want, to make a fruit syrup.

Mix them in with pancake batter.

Make cherry muffins.

Make a pie.

Comment: Pulse them in a food processor, add a little bit of xanthan gum, add a little bit of fruit juice, and blend some more and you have a soft-set sorbet in a minute or so.  If you're using less sweet frozen fruit, you might need to add some sugar or syrup to it.  (I'm trying to remember the proportions ... I want to say it was 1/4 tsp to either 1 or 2 cups of fruit ... juice is by eye 'til you get the consistency you want ... but you probably want to start with 1/4 c. or so for 1c of fruit)

Answer (score 3):

Frozen fruits like that (cherries or cranberries) will give better results when cooked.

Cranberries can be eaten raw, but they are tart and should be eaten very fresh; most of the time they are cooked.

Cherries can be eating raw if they are fresh, when frozen, better to cook them.

Thawing the fruits will render them mushy.

Comment: I find eating frozen fruit like berries or cherries, with just a few minutes of thawing, to be very tasty and refreshing - like ice cream without the extra calories.

Comment: @JohnFeltz - I freeze grapes, whole and unadulterated, for just that reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can eat them frozen or put them in a smoothie frozen.

If you are going to thaw them then do it slowly in the refrigerator.

If you rapid thaw it will create more thermal stress and break the fruit up.

In a delicate fruit like a strawberry a rapid thaw will turn it to a soup.  I worked in restaurants and saw it time and time again.

In freezing same thing.  Cool them first in fridge and then freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I like to suck on frozen cherries. But mostly defrost them and add them to yogurt. Frozen grapes are lovely to chew on, and both cherries and grapes are nice added to a glass of cold water, especially in the summer. I also put cherries, and other fruits in ice lolly Molds, add cherry juice, or other juice, and freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Frozen cherries, the sour ones, are my yearly snack. We fill up zipper bags with kilos of cherries and freeze them. I serve them straight out of the freezer in a bowl, give them a light salting and let them sit for 5 minutes, then dig in. Basically anything sour with salt is amazing.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for the interesting suggestion! I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [answer] - you may want to [edit] your post to remove some of the “duuuude!” slang, we do have a bit of an expectation re. writing style. If a few typos slip, no problem, the community will help out, but you may want to sharpen the actual statement?